# How to bring a bottom UITableViewCells over top ones?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I populate with an array of objects.
Everything works well except the fact that I'd like the bottom cells to be over the top ones but iOS default behaviour is not like that.

I mean, right now, every cells have a button that's out the the cell's rect, and that button is always covered by the cell which is above.

Here are two pictures to show you what I currently have (first picture) and what I'd like to achieve (second picture).

**What I have**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

Any idea on How to achieve that?

Comment: is the red component an image ?

Comment: It's a `UIButton` that's a subview of the cell's `contentView`

Comment: did you tried to set "clipsToBounds" to false on cell and cell.contentview ?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of cells and z-position are a bit tricky.
Of course you can try doing it when table scrolls, but I would not recommend it.

Best will be to prepare cells so they don't overlap with each other.
First will be the data cell and another one will be the cells that connects data cells

I marked division on your preview file

[image: preview]